# Next track does not play in the web browser on iOS 17 in blocked screen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I have a js audio player for html5. When playing music in the background in the browser (any) on the iPhone, the tracks do not switch automatically.

1. Go to the page with the audio player
2. Starting the track
3. Rewinding to the end
4. Minimize the browser to the background
5. After the playback of the running track is completed, the music pauses

My js audio player:

```
  function createTrackItem(index,name,duration){
    var trackItem = document.createElement('div');
    trackItem.setAttribute("class", "playlist-track-ctn");
    trackItem.setAttribute("id", "ptc-"+index);
    trackItem.setAttribute("data-index", index);
    document.querySelector(".playlist-ctn").appendChild(trackItem);

    var playBtnItem = document.createElement('div');
    playBtnItem.setAttribute("class", "playlist-btn-play");
    playBtnItem.setAttribute("id", "pbp-"+index);
    document.querySelector("#ptc-"+index).appendChild(playBtnItem);

    var btnImg = document.createElement('i');
    btnImg.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-play");
    btnImg.setAttribute("height", "40");
    btnImg.setAttribute("width", "40");
    btnImg.setAttribute("id", "p-img-"+index);
    document.querySelector("#pbp-"+index).appendChild(btnImg);

    var trackInfoItem = document.createElement('div');
    trackInfoItem.setAttribute("class", "playlist-info-track");
    trackInfoItem.innerHTML = name
    document.querySelector("#ptc-"+index).appendChild(trackInfoItem);

    var trackDurationItem = document.createElement('div');
    trackDurationItem.setAttribute("class", "playlist-duration");
    trackDurationItem.innerHTML = duration
    document.querySelector("#ptc-"+index).appendChild(trackDurationItem);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < listAudio.length; i++) {
      createTrackItem(i,listAudio[i].name,listAudio[i].duration);
  }
  var indexAudio = 0;

  function loadNewTrack(index){
    var player = document.querySelector('#source-audio')
    player.src = listAudio[index].file
    document.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = listAudio[index].name
    document.title = listAudio[index].name
    this.currentAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    this.currentAudio.load()
    this.toggleAudio()
    this.updateStylePlaylist(this.indexAudio,index)
    this.indexAudio = index;
  }

  var playListItems = document.querySelectorAll(".playlist-track-ctn");

  for (let i = 0; i < playListItems.length; i++){
    playListItems[i].addEventListener("click", getClickedElement.bind(this));
  }

  function getClickedElement(event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < playListItems.length; i++){
      if(playListItems[i] == event.target){
        var clickedIndex = event.target.getAttribute("data-index")
        if (clickedIndex == this.indexAudio ) { // alert('Same audio');
            this.toggleAudio()
        }else{
            loadNewTrack(clickedIndex);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('#source-audio').src = listAudio[indexAudio].file
  document.querySelector('.title').innerHTML = listAudio[indexAudio].name


  var currentAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");

  currentAudio.load()

  currentAudio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('duration')[0].innerHTML = this.getMinutes(this.currentAudio.duration)
  }.bind(this);

  var interval1;

  function toggleAudio() {

    if (this.currentAudio.paused) {
      document.querySelector('#icon-play').style.display = 'none';
      document.querySelector('#icon-pause').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#ptc-'+this.indexAudio).classList.add("active-track");
      this.playToPause(this.indexAudio)
      this.currentAudio.play();
    }else{
      document.querySelector('#icon-play').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#icon-pause').style.display = 'none';
      this.pauseToPlay(this.indexAudio)
      this.currentAudio.pause();
    }
  }

  function pauseAudio() {
    this.currentAudio.pause();
    clearInterval(interval1);
  }

  var timer = document.getElementsByClassName('timer')[0]

  var barProgress = document.getElementById("myBar");


  var width = 0;

  function onTimeUpdate() {
    var t = this.currentAudio.currentTime
    timer.innerHTML = this.getMinutes(t);
    this.setBarProgress();
    if (this.currentAudio.ended) {
      document.querySelector('#icon-play').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#icon-pause').style.display = 'none';
      this.pauseToPlay(this.indexAudio)
      if (this.indexAudio < listAudio.length-1) {
          var index = parseInt(this.indexAudio)+1
          this.loadNewTrack(index)
      }
    }
  }


  function setBarProgress(){
    var progress = (this.currentAudio.currentTime/this.currentAudio.duration)*100;
    document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = progress + "%";
  }


  function getMinutes(t){
    var min = parseInt(parseInt(t)/60);
    var sec = parseInt(t%60);
    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = "0"+sec
    }
    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0"+min
    }
    return min+":"+sec
  }

  var progressbar = document.querySelector('#myProgress')
  progressbar.addEventListener("click", seek.bind(this));


  function seek(event) {
    var percent = event.offsetX / progressbar.offsetWidth;
    this.currentAudio.currentTime = percent * this.currentAudio.duration;
    barProgress.style.width = percent*100 + "%";
  }

  function forward(){
    this.currentAudio.currentTime = this.currentAudio.currentTime + 5
    this.setBarProgress();
  }

  function rewind(){
    this.currentAudio.currentTime = this.currentAudio.currentTime - 5
    this.setBarProgress();
  }


  function next(){
    if (this.indexAudio <listAudio.length-1) {
        var oldIndex = this.indexAudio
        this.indexAudio++;
        updateStylePlaylist(oldIndex,this.indexAudio)
        this.loadNewTrack(this.indexAudio);
    }
  }

  function previous(){
    if (this.indexAudio>0) {
        var oldIndex = this.indexAudio
        this.indexAudio--;
        updateStylePlaylist(oldIndex,this.indexAudio)
        this.loadNewTrack(this.indexAudio);
    }
  }

  function updateStylePlaylist(oldIndex,newIndex){
    document.querySelector('#ptc-'+oldIndex).classList.remove("active-track");
    this.pauseToPlay(oldIndex);
    document.querySelector('#ptc-'+newIndex).classList.add("active-track");
    this.playToPause(newIndex)
  }

  function playToPause(index){
    var ele = document.querySelector('#p-img-'+index)
    ele.classList.remove("fa-play");
    ele.classList.add("fa-pause");
  }

  function pauseToPlay(index){
    var ele = document.querySelector('#p-img-'+index)
    ele.classList.remove("fa-pause");
    ele.classList.add("fa-play");
  }


  function toggleMute(){
    var btnMute = document.querySelector('#toggleMute');
    var volUp = document.querySelector('#icon-vol-up');
    var volMute = document.querySelector('#icon-vol-mute');
    if (this.currentAudio.muted == false) {
       this.currentAudio.muted = true
       volUp.style.display = "none"
       volMute.style.display = "block"
    }else{
      this.currentAudio.muted = false
      volMute.style.display = "none"
      volUp.style.display = "block"
    }
  }
```

I tried running music in the background on Android 11 tracks switch automatically. I was looking for information about the specifics of safari and js